# Occupancy vs mark-recapture?

Tags: model, ecology, capture-mark-recapture

What are the differences between occupancy models and mark-recapture in ecology? As I understand it, we use occupancy models when we aren't sure if detectability is a given (not sure of presence/ absence).  Mark-recapture is used when we know the target species is present.  Is this assessment of the uses correct? How does this translate to differences in mathematics?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a statistical question, or just a question about ecology?

Comment: @gung It is a statistical question with an ecological application! My question is 1) about the appropriate application of statistics and 2) about the mathematical differences between two statistical models.  I thought it would be appropriate for this forum but if not I can take it elsewhere. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: That sounds fine for CV. It just may be ambiguous for people who aren't in ecology (which is most users here).